# Understanding how 'cat' command works

Tags: unix

cat concatenates files or stdin and redirects it to stdout.

```
$ cat file1 > file5 file2 file3 file4
```

concatenates file1, file2, file3 and file 4 and writes it to file5.

```
$ cat file1 > file5 < file2 file3 file4
```

concatenates file1, file3 and file4 (not file2) and writes to file5

Please explain these outputs

Examples of what happens:

```
~/test$ echo "this is file 1"> file1
~/test$ echo "this is file 2"> file2
~/test$ echo "this is file 3"> file3
~/test$ echo "this is file 4">file4
~/test$ cat file1 > file5 file2 file3 file4
~/test$ cat file5
this is file 1
this is file 2
this is file 3
this is file 4
~/test$ cat file1 > file5  < file2 file3 file4
~/test$ cat file5
this is file 1
this is file 3
this is file 4
```

Comment: It's not programming-related - probably belongs on http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I politely disagree. I think it fits well with questions on SF

Comment: http://www.shlomifish.org/humour/bits/Mastering-Cat/

Comment: @Ignacio: You are right. I need some sleep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is less about how `cat` works, and more about shell redirection. The shell processes the command line before it runs the program. It's easier to see if you push all the io redirection to the end of the command. The first becomes:

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 > file5
```

The shell then changes the output of cat from the terminal to file5. *This is completely independent of cat.*

The second command is then

```
cat file1 file3 file4 >file5 <file2
```

This this changes the standard input from the keyboard to `file2` and the output, like before, to file5. In this instance, because there are files specified on the command line, cat ignores the standard input, reading only from the 1, 3, and 4. The `-` argument tells cat to read from standard input, so

```
cat file1 - file3 file4 >file5 < file2
```

Would output the contents of files 1-4 to file 5.

Comment: cat < file1 > file2 writes contents of file1 in file2. Why doesn't this happen in the second example in the question?

Comment: That runs cat with no arguments, meaning cat will read from stdin, but with arguments, cat will only read from stdin when given a `-`

Answer (score 1):

Only one redirection takes place in the shell; the rest are passed as arguments.

The first command is

```
cat file1 file2 file3 file4 > file5
```

The second command is

```
cat file1 file3 file4 > file5 < file2
```

The second command doesn't include `file2` because `cat` was never told to read from stdin with `-`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your last line. What is "-"?

Answer (score 1):

Redirections can be placed anywhere in the command line, although the usual way is at the end.

<s>Your second statement is incorrect. file2 should be is ignored.</s> (was corrected later)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create simple bash file

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $@
```

And run

```
./bash.sh file1 file2 file3 file4 > file5
```

gives you

```
file1 file2 file3 file4

./bash.sh file1 file3 file4 >file5 <file2
```

gives you

```
file1 file3 file4
```

in file 5 you see list of arguments, what cat do is that takes list of arguments and write it to the std output, that's why file 2 is ignored, it's not a parameter, it's an input in fact

if you want cat to read from std input assign - after the command

```
cat file1 > file5 < file2 file3 file4 -
```

This will write

```
1111
3333
4444
2222
```

to the file5

< means redirection of std input, if you write

```
cat file1 > file5 file3 file4 -
```

it reads from file1, file3, and file4 **and your keyboard** to the file5